# How to disable NodeTree (parents and children) in primeng?

Tags: angular, pointers, primeng, disable, boost-propertytree

This is my HTML code:

```
<p-tree id="tree" *ngIf="node"  [value]="node" selectionMode="null"  [(selection)]="selectedFile" (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)" (onNodeUnselect)="nodeUnselect($event)" >
                <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default" >
                  <b>{{node.data.description}}</b>
                </ng-template>
              </p-tree>
```

I need to disable all the tree. A disable control would be enough or replace hand pointer with a cursor pointer.
Any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- set `node.selectable=false;` for all the parent and child node by using recursive function

```js
    disableRecursive(node:TreeNode){
        node.selectable = false;
        if (node.children){
            node.children.forEach( childNode => {
                this.disableRecursive(childNode);
            } );
        }
    }
```